# self split insert in oracle interval partition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert, partitioning

i have very strange problem.

i have some insert into interval partition table.

The insert take a long time - but the interesting thing is that after some time that it's running - it's just stop it's operation, and starting the same insert from the start - and it all happing itself!

I have a problem to post here a screen-capture of the OEM but it's look like that:

insert1 - start time 12:00:00, end time 12:55:18

insert2 - start time 12:55:18, end time 13:53:42

insert3 - start time 13:53:42, end time 14:50:16

and so on for only one insert operation!!!

and in the sql developer the query not realy end at all...

it behave like it is still in the process.

there is no parallel hint or something...

and it is happening only for insert into interval-partition table.

when the insert is to non-partition table - it's all normal..

any idea???

thanks.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to describe. An insert is slow, or is hanging and never completing? If it's never-ending, do you have uncommitted changes to that table in another session? If a single insert is taking nearly an hour - what is actually being inserted, a single set of values or the result of a query (insert ... select) - if the latter, how long does the query take to complete on its own, and how many rows are involved?

Comment: thanks for your comment. the insert speed is ok but it just never ends. lets say that with no-interval-partitions it take an 1 hour. so with the interval partition table it work 1 hour, and after that hour, the oem shows that the command ends and start a new one, but the command itself in the developer still processing.. 3,4 times.. maybe more, i dont know. i do not have uncomitted changes. i'm sure about that.

Comment: Reprocessing the same insert; or moving on to a different insert from the same script? Oracle can restart an operation sometimes. Are any other changes being made to the target table at the same time? Or any of the source tables? Maybe the query you're using for the insert needs to be tuned anyway, if it's taking that long, but that might not entirely solve the problem.

Comment: [Here's a reference to what you might be seeing.](http://oracle-randolf.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/dml-operations-on-partitioned-tables.html) If you have access to MOS it's probably worth looking at the documents that blog post mentions.

Comment: the same insert. it looks like oracle stop the current insert and just start it from the beginning... there are no changes on the table... i even try it - i created identical table and tried to do the insert to there - it's a new table, no one make anything on it - and it's still give the same thing...

Comment: That blog post says changes to the queried tables can cause it though, not just the target. Even stats gathering, from the example given. Maybe you have a scheduled job that's interfering? I'd see if there was anything helpful in the MOS documents. Or maybe that isn't exactly what you're seeing - do the diagnostics mentioned match what you see in OEM?

Comment: Hi, I think you right! i look in this article.. until now i check if there is a change on the target table. but now i understand the issue, and i think that actually there is a job that giving a grant on one of the involved tables.. so maybe this is the reason. so first - thanks a lot! now i need to think about a solution... because as i see in MOS - this is an oracle bug.. and the way to avoid it is to do not apply ddl according the insert.. but this is such a problem. because this job is neccessery, and running every hour. and the insert takes few more minutes..

Comment: Maybe you can insert into a non-partitoned staging table (or GTT) first, and then copy from there to your real target table? Just a thought...

Comment: @user2671057  FWIW, the bug is closed as "not a bug". I would be surprised if running a grant on the object was the cause of the invalidation.

Comment: Alex, thanks, i'm checking this job whit the ddl, maybe i can change it's hours. Bob, why not a bug? they display it as a bug... about the grant - actually, i will be a littel bit suprised too.. but in that job there is a create synonym on tables too... maybe this is the problematic ddl. i'm checking all the options.

Comment: @user2671057. It's "not a bug" because it's working as designed. That's not to say the design could be better. However, change to the design would be too large in scope for a "bug fix"; it would have to be done as a project. Are you able to reproduce the problem just using a grant?

Comment: Hi all, 
the problem as we thought, was becasue of the grant. when the grant doesn't execute - it is working great. in my specific case - i cause the prcoess with the grant to don't execute the grant command in this time. it's solve the problem. thanks all of you!